# Make Zathura open by default a document with the window size

Tags: linux, configuration, pdf, zathura

I want to configure my Zathura so that when I open a document automatically the size of the page of pdf adjusts to the size of the window.

**Practical example**

If i close the Zathura like this:

[image]

When i open it again it stays the same size.

I want that when I open it again it automatically adjusts to the width of the window regardless of what state it had previously.

An example of what I mean is when you press the "s" it automatically adjusts to the entire window.

I tried this in zathurarc but doesn't work. Even with "width" but it does nothing regardless of the option I tried changing colors and worked so I know that zathura is reading the file correctly.

```
set adjust-open "best-fit"
```

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for a solution to this, and like you, I couldn't get `adjust-open` to work either. I also couldn't find any discussion about this in the [Zathura issue tracker](https://git.pwmt.org/pwmt/zathura/-/issues). The other answer mentioning `set adjust_window width` doesn't work.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution within Zathura itself, but after some fiddling with `xdotool`, I whipped up the following shell script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
zathura "$@" & PID="$!"

while true; do
  window_id="$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid "$PID")"
  if [ -n "$window_id" ]; then
    xdotool windowactivate --sync "$window_id" windowfocus --sync "$window_id" \
      key s key --delay 0 g g
    break
  fi
done
```

This launches `zathura` and waits for a window to be created for that process ID. Then it activates and focuses the window, and sends the `s` keystroke to fit the document to the window width, followed by `gg` to go to the beginning. I don't like Zathura remembering the document position, but you can remove the second `key --delay 0 g g` if you don't need this.

I also have the following in my `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc` file:

```
set window-height 3000
set window-width 3000
```

This starts the window "maximized".

Note that `xdotool` only works on X11, and I'm not aware of alternatives for Wayland.

This could be much easier if Zathura allowed the `feedkeys` shortcut function to be used outside of `map`, or any of the other shortcut functions for that matter.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thank @imiric very much for the answer, and I am also grateful for you taking the time and effort to write a detailed answer.

Answer (score -1):

Edit your `zathurarc` (usually in `.config/zathura/` folder) to include

```
set adjust_window width
```